# Unit Testing Error: py.test WinError5

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I am trying to do unit testing in Python (intermediate skill level). I've had this error for the past couple of months, and after many hours of searching for a solution on Google, I have not been able to fix this. The issue is that I am being denied permission to certain folders on my computer despite running conda as an admin and being the listed owner of each file.

```
(base) C:\Users\danie>py.test
============================= test session starts =============================
platform win32 -- Python 3.6.5, pytest-3.5.1, py-1.5.3, pluggy-0.7.1
rootdir: C:\Users\danie, inifile:
plugins: remotedata-0.2.1, openfiles-0.3.0, doctestplus-0.1.3, arraydiff-0.2
collected 0 items / 1 errors

=================================== ERRORS ====================================
______________________________ ERROR collecting  ______________________________
AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py\_error.py:66: in checked_call
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
E   PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\danie\\AppData\\Local\\Application Data'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py\_path\common.py:377: in visit
    for x in Visitor(fil, rec, ignore, bf, sort).gen(self):
AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py\_path\common.py:429: in gen
    for p in self.gen(subdir):
AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py\_path\common.py:429: in gen
    for p in self.gen(subdir):
AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py\_path\common.py:429: in gen
    for p in self.gen(subdir):
AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py\_path\common.py:414: in gen
    entries = path.listdir()
AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py\_path\local.py:387: in listdir
    names = py.error.checked_call(os.listdir, self.strpath)
AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py\_error.py:86: in checked_call
    raise cls("%s%r" % (func.__name__, args))
E   py.error.EBUSY: [Resource device]: listdir('C:\\Users\\danie\\AppData\\Local\\Application Data',)
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 errors during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
=========================== 1 error in 0.20 seconds ===========================
```

Comment: You need to include the error text in your question (instead of providing a link to a picture of the text)!

Comment: My issue is a permission error. py.test should be able to run without a test file, where the output is something like the following:

============================= test session starts =============================
platform darwin -- Python 3.6.0, pytest-3.0.5, py-1.4.32, pluggy-0.4.0
rootdir: /Users/Student, inifile:
collected 0 items
========================= no tests ran in 0.02 seconds ========================

Comment: it can, but the %USERPROFILE% directory is a very bad place to do so. Try it from a directory that doesn't contain system directories.